# How to make TypeScript "know" that a public instance property ($locale) is added to Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using [v-localize](https://neetjn.github.io/v-localize/) in my Vue app and I'm migrating to TypeScript. v-localize is added to the app like this:

```
//...
const Localize = require('v-localize'); // was import before migration to TS
import { locales } from './localize';

//...
Vue.use(Localize);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  localize: locales,
  render: (h: Function) => h(App) //# h: Vue.CreateElement? , => Vue.VNode?
});
```

which brings

> Error:(13, 3) TS2769: No overload matches this call. [....]

and which I currently suppress with

```
} as any);
```

in the last line; and in scripts (as opposed to in templates) it is used like this:

```
const myLocalizedString = this.$locale({i: 'scopeName.stringName'})
```

where `$locale` gets highlighted with

> Unresolved function or method `$locale()`

Again, I can suppress it like this:

```
(this as any).$locale({i: 'scopeName.stringName'})
```

but I wonder if there's a more consistent (and less verbose) approach. How do I make TypeScript aware of both new field of Vue config and of the `$locale` method?

Comment: It appears that this package does not have support for Typescript. You can try to implement that yourself. Here are some useful resources: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: @Komninos just in case you are interested, you may check out my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my partial solution:

- to use `import Localize from 'v-localize'` instead of `const Localize = require('v-localize')` I added a file `v-localize.d.ts` like this:

  ```
    declare module 'v-localize' {
        export default function Localize (): any;
    }
  ```

  surely this is not a dedicated typing but is good enough for this particular task
- to access `.$locale` in components and get type suggestions of its argument, I've introduced another file `v-localize-vue.d.ts` ([module augmentation example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins)):

  ```
    import Vue from 'vue'

    type localeArgument = {
        i: string
    }

    declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
        interface Vue {
            $locale: (a: localeArgument) => string
        }
    }
  ```
- to remove the `} as any);` bit from the Vue options, I've added to `v-localize-vue.d.ts` (in accord with the same doc):

  ```
    declare module 'vue/types/options' {
        interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
            localize?: any
        }
    }
  ```

I call the solution "partial" since I use `any` in the first and the third bit and I haven't digged whether my `localeArgument` type is accurate (perhaps the object can contain other fields and `i` is not required).