# How to apply a function type interface to a non-variable function?

Tags: typescript

### The problem

TypeScript allows to create [interfaces for functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types):

```
interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
}
```

and the docs also tell how to define a variable function that implements such an interface:

```
let mySearch: SearchFunc;
```

However, I'm trying to tell TS that a function defined as

```
export function Vuikit()
```

implements that interface. How do I go about that?

### Some attempts and context

```
export function Vuikit: MyFuncInterface
```

gives an error;

```
export function Vuikit(): MyFuncInterface
```

is something that has no arguments and returns `MyFuncInterface` and doesn't *implement* `MyFuncInterface`.

Since I'm trying to write a .d.ts file for an existing package, I can't do

```
let Vuikit: PluginObject<any> | PluginFunction<any>; // gives  TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Vuikit'.
export Vuikit;
```

To provide more detail (may be it's an XY problem): [the patch I've used for v-localize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58397939/3995261) doesn't work in this case: with this vuikit.d.ts

```
// a minimal implementation to suppress warnings, to be improved later
// as an example, see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/vue-select
declare module 'vuikit' {
    export function Vuikit (): any;
}
```

when I write

```
Vue.use(Vuikit);
```

I get the following error:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.    Overload 1 of 2, '(plugin: PluginObject | PluginFunction, options?: unknown): VueConstructor', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'typeof import("vuikit")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject | PluginFunction'.       Property 'install' is missing in type 'typeof import("vuikit")' but required in type 'PluginObject'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(plugin: PluginObject | PluginFunction, ...options: any[]): VueConstructor', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'typeof import("vuikit")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject | PluginFunction'.       Property 'install' is missing in type 'typeof import("vuikit")' but required in type 'PluginObject'.

As the last resort, I can do

```
Vue.use(Vuikit as any);
```

but I'd like to avoid this and make this more consistent. The idea is to try to tell that `Vuikit` implements either `PluginObject<any>` or `PluginFunction<any>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter functions in the source module are defined as `export function() { ... }`, because you are writing .d.ts - that's how your code would typecheck, not how it's implemented. So, if you have a callabe interface, just define your functions with `const func: YourInterface`.

And, given that Typescript complaints about `typeof import()`, you are missing `export default` in your ambient declaration.

So, the result would be something like

```
declare module "Vuikit" {
    ...
    const Vuikit: PluginObject<any>;
    export default Vuikit;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I somehow missed the `default` bit when created this .d.ts, so just adding it fixed the issue, but thanks again for pointing how to improve this using an actual interface

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function like:

```
type SearchFunc = (source: string, subString: string) => boolean;

declare module 'vuikit' {
    export const Vuikit: SearchFunc;
}
```

Comment: please read more carefully the "Since I'm trying to write a .d.ts file for an existing package, I can't do" bit. `const` or `let` doesn't matter in this case I suppose

Comment: ahh my bad, I overlooked that part, I've edited the answer.. though I think you mentioned you've already tried this.. I don't get any errors on my side.

Comment: I see the parameters are gone.. edited once more :)